# How to extract Attributes along with their names and datatypes from an XSD file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have having trouble extracting attributes along with their names and datatypes and datatype length from XSD file.

My XSD file is of the following structure. There are basically 3 columns in this XSD (Action_needed,Company id,Company Name). From this XSD I need to extract the column names, their datatypes and the maxlength of the datatype. I need to use C# for this.

Would appreciate any inputs regarding this. Thanks in advance. I tried many blogs/posts in this forum but could not figure this out.

```
       <xs:element name="Companies">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element ref="Z" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="Z">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:attribute ref="c1"/>
         <xs:attribute ref="c2" use="required" />
         <xs:attribute ref="c3" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:attribute name="c1">
      <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>Action_needed</xs:appinfo>
    <xs:documentation>Action (Add/Update/Delete)</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="U"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
      </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:attribute>
   <xs:attribute name="c2">
      <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>Company ID</xs:appinfo>
    <xs:documentation>My Suppliers > Supplier Header > Name</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
         <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="sqltypes:int"/>
       </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:attribute>
   <xs:attribute name="c3">
      <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>Company Name</xs:appinfo>
    <xs:documentation>My Suppliers > Supplier Header > Name</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
         <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar">
      <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
             </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:attribute>
 </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got a xsd document like above, you may need a code like that.

here is a console version

my xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="transfer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="sourceGLN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                            <xs:element name="actionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="destinationGLN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="P" /> <!-- Mal Alim (Purchase) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="S" /> <!-- Satis (Sale) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="C" /> <!-- Cancel Sale (Cancel) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="R" /> <!-- Iade (Return) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="D" /> <!-- Deaktivasyon (Deactivation) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="M" /> <!-- Uretim (Manufacture) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="I" /> <!-- Ithalat (Import) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="X" /> <!-- Ihrac (eXport) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="O" /> <!-- Sarf (cOnsume) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="N" /> <!-- Bilgi (iNformation) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="T" /> <!-- Devir (Transfer) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="L" /> <!-- Devir Iptal (canceL Transfer) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="F" /> <!-- Aktarim (non-its transFer) -->
                            <xs:enumeration value="K" /> <!-- Aktarim Iptal (non-its cancel transfer) -->
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="shipTo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="documentNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="documentDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="carrier" type="carrierType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="carrierType">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="productList" type="productListType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="carrier" type="carrierType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="carrierLabel" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:length value="20" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="containerType" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="productListType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="serialNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="GTIN" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="lotNumber" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="productionDate" type="xs:date" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute name="expirationDate" type="xs:date" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="PONumber" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and here is my c# code for this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
            schemaSet.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "C:\\Chandan\\myxsdfile.xsd");
            schemaSet.Compile();

            XmlSchema xmlSchema = null;
            foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
            {
                xmlSchema = schema;
            }

            DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
            myDS.ReadXmlSchema("C:\\Chandan\\myxsdfile.xsd");

            foreach (object item in xmlSchema.Items)
            {
                XmlSchemaElement schemaElement = item as XmlSchemaElement;
                XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = item as XmlSchemaComplexType;

                if (schemaElement != null)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Schema Element: {0}", schemaElement.Name);

                    XmlSchemaType schemaType = schemaElement.SchemaType;
                    XmlSchemaComplexType schemaComplexType = schemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

                    if (schemaComplexType != null)
                    {
                        XmlSchemaParticle particle = schemaComplexType.Particle;
                        XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;

                        if (sequence != null)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                            {
                                Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                                      childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                            }

                        }
                        if (schemaComplexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
                        {
                            IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = schemaComplexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                XmlSchemaAttribute attribute = (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;

                                Console.Out.WriteLine("      Attribute/Type: {0}", attribute.Name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (complexType != null)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Complex Type: {0}", complexType.Name);
                    OutputElements(complexType.Particle);
                    if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
                    {
                        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = complexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            XmlSchemaAttribute attribute = (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("      Attribute/Type: {0}", attribute.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Out.WriteLine();
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void OutputElements(XmlSchemaParticle particle)
        {
            XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice choice = particle as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll all = particle as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (sequence != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("  Sequence");

                for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    XmlSchemaElement childElement = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
                    XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
                    XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
                    XmlSchemaAll innerAll = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

                    if (childElement != null)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                              childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                    }
                    else OutputElements(sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
                }
            }
            else if (choice != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("  Choice");
                for (int i = 0; i < choice.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    XmlSchemaElement childElement = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
                    XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
                    XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
                    XmlSchemaAll innerAll = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

                    if (childElement != null)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                              childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                    }
                    else OutputElements(choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
                }

                Console.Out.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (all != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("  All");
                for (int i = 0; i < all.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    XmlSchemaElement childElement = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
                    XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
                    XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
                    XmlSchemaAll innerAll = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

                    if (childElement != null)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                              childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                    }
                    else OutputElements(all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
                }
                Console.Out.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
                Console.Write("WARNING: ");
            else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                Console.Write("ERROR: ");

            Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ran this code on the file and it is displaying only null rows.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but the start of my xsd contains the below text.                                                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />

Comment: try with modified one's and find out where you are missing